# Proof Explanation: $\rho(\tau)=\rho(\tau\sigma)+dim[Im(\sigma)\cap K(\tau)]$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

**$\tau$ and $\sigma$ are linear transformations. $K(\tau)$ means kernel of $\tau$. $\rho$ is the rank. $dim$ means dimension**

The domain and codomain wasn't stated clearly in the book so i think we'll assume $\sigma: U\rightarrow V$ and $\tau:V\rightarrow W$

Proof:

Let $\tau'$ be a new linear transformation such that $\tau':Im(\sigma)\rightarrow W$, and

> $\forall \overline{\alpha}\in Im(\sigma),
> \tau'(\overline{\alpha})=\tau(\overline{\alpha})$... **Does this mean that** $Im(\tau')=Im(\tau)$?

.

> Then $K(\tau')=Im(\sigma)\cap K(\tau)$... **Would this be because** $Im(\sigma)\cap K(\tau)=K(\tau)?$ **and** $Im(\tau')=Im(\tau)$?

and

> $\rho(\tau')=dim\{\tau[Im(\sigma)]\}=dim(\tau\sigma(U))=\rho(\tau\sigma)$... **Is this also because** $Im(\tau')=Im(\tau)$?

Then Theorem 1.6 takes the form, $\rho(\tau')+v(\tau')=dim\{Im(\sigma)\}$ or $\rho(\tau)=\rho(\tau\sigma)+dim[Im(\sigma)\cap K(\tau)]$. $\Bbb{QED}$

Comment: This proof is taken from evar nering's linear algebra text.

Comment: What is $\rho$ and $d$? What is the domain of $\tau$ and $\sigma$?

Comment: i just edited. thanks for pointing it out. $d$ is supposed to be $dim$, while $\tau$ and $\sigma$ are linear transformations.

Comment: as for the domain and codomain. it didn't say exactly what which also puzzled me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems as if $\sigma(U)=Im(\sigma)\subseteq V$. Then

> $\forall \overline{\alpha}\in Im(\sigma),\tau'(\overline{\alpha})=\tau(\overline{\alpha})$

would mean that $Im(\tau')\subseteq Im(\tau).$ In fact $Im(\tau')=Im(\tau|_{Im(\sigma)})$.

Also $$K(\tau')=\{x: x\in Im(\sigma)\wedge \tau'(x)=0\}=\{x: x\in Im(\sigma)\wedge \tau(x)=0\}=\{x: x\in Im(\sigma)\wedge x\in K(\tau)\}=Im(\sigma)\cap K(\tau)$$ and 
$$\rho(\tau')=dim(Im(\tau'))=dim(Im(\tau|_{Im(\sigma)}))=dim(\tau\sigma(U))=\rho(\tau\sigma)$$

Comment: what does $\tau\mid_{Im(\sigma)}$ mean? I'll try to figure this out tomorrow. I'm too tired now. thanks!

Comment: It is $\tau$ with its domain restricted to $Im(\sigma)$.

Comment: So if $Im(\tau')=Im(\tau\mid_{Im(\sigma)})$, then $Im(\tau')=Im(\tau\sigma)$? Because $Im(\tau\sigma)$ is image of $\tau$ **"applied to"** to $\sigma$?

Comment: Yes that's right.