# $A$ and $B$ are two $n\times n$ matrices; suppose that $Rank(AB) = Rank(B)$. Show that $N(L_A) \cap R(L_B) =\{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n×n$ matrices and suppose that $\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank} \rank(AB) = \rank(B)$. Show that $N(L_A) ∩ R(L_B) ={0}$ (where $L_A$ is the map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ sending $v$ to $Av$ and $L_B$ is the map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ sending $v$ to $Bv$, as usual).

All right. I know that according to rank-nullity theorem, $N(L_{AB})=N(L_B)$. But what is the usage of this condition? I am stuck here. 
Also, I have tried to use contradictions. Since If we assume that $N(L_A) ∩ R(L_B) =\{v\}$ Then there must be $L_B(p)=v$ and $L_A(v)=0$. Thus $L_{AB}(p)=0$. Thus $p \in L(AB)$ but is that useful?

Comment: bowwow123  Please edit your question post by adding your question, and include your efforts on the exercise, and specify where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is my first time using this community.

Comment: No problem, meow123.  It can be hard to grasp the norms of this site when very new to it.  Thanks for improving your post.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3232684

Comment: See as well the interesting property established here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2641936 out of which your result follows.

Comment: Thank you Marie!

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, we have the row space of $AB$ is a subspace of the rowspace of $B$. Since we are given that $rank(AB)=rank(B)$, then the row space of $AB$ is equal to the row space of $B$. Hence, the nullspace of $AB$ must be equal to the nullspace of $B$.

Suppose on the contrary that $N(L_A) \cap R(L_B) \ne \{0\}$, then we can find $p, v \ne 0$ such that

$Av=0$ and $v=Bp$ that is

$Bp \ne 0$ but $ABp=0$

That is $p$ is in the nullspace of $AB$ but not in the nullspace of $B$, which is a contradiction.

- Edit to response to a comment:

Note that $AB$ and $B$ need not share the same range space.

For example, let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, then $AB=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, the row space is the same but the range space differs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! But I don't quite understand that according to the Rank-Nullity theorem. I could know that the dimension of nullspace of AB must be equal to the dimension of the nullspace of B. How could I know the two spaces are equal?

Comment: One way to view it is if two matrices that are row equivalent share the same nullspace.

Comment: My idea is that they share the same Rn and they have the same space of range. Thus, the remaining space ( the nullspace) must be same. Am I right?

Comment: they need not share the same range space. I have given a counterexample in the answer space :)

Comment: seems like I have to review my linear algebra textbook